# How do that react-router 5.1.2 nested route not show the parent component only child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like represent my database content in my react app.

My database structure similar: array in object that inside also array.

I solve it but the parent component is stay.
I would like only child component visible (or renderer in DOM) if I clicked in parent component
I can reach it in react router 5.1 and not in 6.

database

```
const topics = [
  {
    name: "xxxx",
    id: "xxxx",
    description: "xxx",
    resources: [
      {
        name: "xxx",
        id: "xxx",
        description: "xxx",
        url: "xxx",
      },
      {
        name: "xxxx",
        id: "xxxxxx",
        description: "xxxxx",
        url: "xxxxx",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "xxxx",
    id: "xxxxx",
    description: "xxxxx",
    resources: [
      {
        name: "xxxx",
        id: "xxxx",
        description: "xxxxx",
        url: "xxxx",
      },
      {
        name: "xxxx",
        id: "xxx",
        description: "xxxxx",
        url: "xxxxx",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "xxxxx",
    id: "xxxxx",
    description: "xxxxx",
    resources: [
      {
        name: "xxxx",
        id: "xxxx",
        description: "xxxxx",
        url: "xxxx",
      },
      {
        name: "xxxx",
        id: "xxx",
        description: "xxxxx",
        url: "xxxx",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Components

```
function Home() {
  return <h1>HOME</h1>;
}
  
function Resource() {
  const { topicId, subId } = useParams();
  
  const topic = topics
    .find(({ id }) => id === topicId)
    .resources.find(({ id }) => id === subId);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{topic.name}</h3>
      <p>{topic.description}</p>
      <a href={topic.url}>More info.</a>
    </div>
  );
}
  
function Topic() {
  const { topicId } = useParams();
  const { url, path } = useRouteMatch();
  
  const topic = topics.find(({ id }) => id === topicId);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{topic.name}</h2>
      <p>{topic.description}</p>
  
      <ul>
        {topic.resources.map((sub) => (
          <li key={sub.id}>
            <Link to={`${url}/${sub.id}`}>{sub.name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  
      <hr />
  
      <Route path={`${path}/:subId`}>
        <Resource />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}
  
function Topics() {
  const { url, path } = useRouteMatch();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <ul>
        {topics.map(({ name, id }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <Link to={`${url}/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  
      <hr />
  
      <Route path={`${path}/:topicId`}>
        <Topic />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}
  
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={{ width: 1000, margin: "0 auto" }}>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
  
        <hr />
  
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/topics">
          <Topics />
        </Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering descendent routes, which means each parent/ancestor component necessarily needs to be matched ***and*** rendered in order for the children/descendent components to be rendered.

If you are wanting to only render one-at-a-time of either the `Topics`, `Topic`, and `Resource` components then all the routes should be declared in the root within a `Switch` so they are ***exclusively*** matched and rendered.

Example:

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/topics/:topicId/:subId" component={Resource} />
        <Route path="/topics/:topicId" component={Topic} />
        <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Resource

```
function Resource() {
  const { topicId, subId } = useParams();

  const topic = topics
    .find(({ id }) => id === topicId)
    .resources.find(({ id }) => id === subId);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{topic.name}</h3>
      <p>{topic.description}</p>
      <a href={topic.url}>More info.</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Topic

```
function Topic() {
  const { topicId } = useParams();
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  const topic = topics.find(({ id }) => id === topicId);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{topic.name}</h2>
      <p>{topic.description}</p>

      <ul>
        {topic.resources.map((sub) => (
          <li key={sub.id}>
            <Link to={`${url}/${sub.id}`}>{sub.name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Topics

```
function Topics() {
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <ul>
        {topics.map(({ name, id }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <Link to={`${url}/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-do-that-react-router-5-1-2-nested-route-not-show-the-parent-component-only-c]